# find the last occurence of characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, magento

I'm wondering in which way I could take "widget" expression from that piece of code:

```
blablablalbadsj kds {{widget type="Magento\FooBard\Block\Widget\Script" wysywig_text="<img src='{{media url='wysiwyg/something.png'}}' alt='' />"}} ksakkdkkcxz {{media url='wysiwyg/something2.png'}}
```

Finally, I wanna have that:

```
{{widget type="Magento\FooBard\Block\Widget\Script" wysywig_text="<img src='{{media url='wysiwyg/something.png'}}' alt='' />"}}
```

I have been thinking about that and I have regular expression like that:

```
/\{\{widget(.*?)\}}/
```

but this doesn't work, it's only matching:

```
{{widget type="Bold\Gtm\Block\Widget\Script" wysywig_text="<img src='{{media url='wysiwyg/compare_brightness.png'}}
```

without: alt='' />"

Comment: What's the logic for which `}}` should end the match?

Comment: You don't want the last `}}`, and you don't want the first `}}`. How is it supposed to know which one you really want?

Comment: If you want to balance the `{{` with `}}`, regular expressions are not good at that. You should use a more powerful parser.

Comment: @Barmar I use that in WYSIWYG Editor in Magento, I wanna pull out all sentence with }} in the end

Comment: you can create a parser to count ( the opened and closed tags ) , see my snippet

Comment: It is an almost one liner with XRegExp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is not to use Regexps for this, since that string is not regular. So attempts to parse it using regular expressions is going to be very difficulty.

```js
var str =`blablablalbadsj kds {{widget type="Magento\FooBard\Block\Widget\Script" wysywig_text="<img src='{{media url='wysiwyg/something.png'}}' alt='' />"}} ksakkdkkcxz {{media url='wysiwyg/something2.png'}}`

var startWdigetPos = str.indexOf("{{widget"),endWidgetPost = 0;
const regex = /{{|}}/mg;


var openedTags=0;
var closedTags=0;
while ((m = regex.exec(str.substr(startWdigetPos))) !== null) {
      // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    if (m[0]=="{{"){
      openedTags++;
    }else if (m[0]="}}"){
      closedTags++;
      
    }
    if (openedTags === closedTags){
     endWidgetPost = regex.lastIndex ;
     break;
    }
    
}
if (endWidgetPost){
  console.log(str.substr(startWdigetPos,endWidgetPost));
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment. Or give a solution that uses a parser.